# dependencies.dependency.version' is missing error

Tags: java, maven-2, osgi-bundle

I am trying to create a bundle using apache maven. When I run `mvn clean install` command it is giving the below error:

> dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api.jar

I have placed that ‘servlet-api.jar’ inside resource folder of my project

Could any anyone please tell where should I place that jar file?

UPDATE:
 Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <parent>
   <artifactId>felix-parent</artifactId>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <relativePath>../pom/pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

 <name>Maven Bundle Plugin</name>
 <description>
  Provides a maven plugin that supports creating an OSGi bundle
  from the contents of the compilation classpath along with its
  resources and dependencies. Plus a zillion other features.
  The plugin uses the Bnd tool (http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd)
 </description>

 <scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/bundleplugin</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/bundleplugin</developerConnection>
  <url>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/bundleplugin</url>
 </scm>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>
        <!-- Provided APIs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

 <reporting>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <component>12311143</component>
     <versionPrefix>maven-bundle-plugin-</versionPrefix>
     <statusIds>Resolved,Closed</statusIds>
     <maxEntries>1000</maxEntries>
     <issueManagementSystems>
      <issueManagementSystem>JIRA</issueManagementSystem>
     </issueManagementSystems>
     <useJql>true</useJql>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </reporting>

</project>
```

Thanks
Anderson

Comment: Please show us your pom.xml. You obviously missed the `<verion>` for the `<dependency>` `servlet-api`.

Comment: Please find my pom.xml

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't added the `version` tag in `dependency`.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>   //Add the version.
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

I had this same error for a slightly different reason.

My project uses dependency management (has 2 `<dependencyManagement>` sections for some reason) and has many modules and sub-modules.

*Top level* pom had:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

*Sub-level* pom had

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

*Leaf pom* had

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

To fix it I removed the `<dependencyManagement>` section from the mid-level pom and changed the *leaf pom* to have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The message is quite clear: inside the `dependencies` element of your pom, you have a `dependency` element with the artefact `javax.servlet:servlet-api.jar`. And inside this `dependency` element, there must be a version element, but you didn't provide it.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Provided APIs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>

        <!-- missing version here: -->
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that 3.0 is just an example. Provide the right version.

Comment: Thanks..Actually i have more than 20 dependencies in my POM. i knew groupid,artifactId but i dont know the version exactly. Is there any way to include?

Comment: any way to include what? You really should know which version of the servlet API you want to use. Nobody can guess for you.

Comment: I have found all the version except two version one is
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
I knew the above version is correct. But maven unable to find it. But it gave alternate way to import it as
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.day.cq -DartifactId=cq-commons -Dversion=5.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

what does it url, /path/to/file, id?
Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the dependency and along with that version and scope is optional.
the latest version of javax.servlet is 3.0-alpha-1 at this point of time.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```